# How can I use an array from a class in another class?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I have a class which a list is defined

```
class PVData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.placelist = []
        for i in ARRAYS:
            self.placelist.append(i)
```

How can I refer to this list in another class which houses all GUI interaction elements, so these list items can used in a OptionMenu

```
class PVPlotApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        lst = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"] ##Would be the list above
        master = Tk()

        var = StringVar(master)
        var.set(lst[0])
        OptionMenu(master, var, *lst).pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like is `pvd` is an instance (via `pvd = PVData()`) then you can access using

```
pvd.placelist
```

I don't quite see what this achieves, though - you may want to be more specific.